# How do I automatically update a ModifiedAt field with ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: ado.net

Ruby on Rails has [magic timestamping fields](http://wiki.rubyonrails.com/rails/pages/Timestamping) that are automatically updated when a record is created or updated. I'm trying to find similar functionality in Entity Framework. I've considered database triggers and a SavingChanges event handler. Is there a more obvious method I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to a SavingChanges event handler. [Details on my blog](http://rabblerule.blogspot.com/2008/10/automatic-timestamping-for-entity.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL Server, use a timestamp field. The value itself is meaningless, other than to tell you whether the record has been touched since your last retrieve.